# Error "signature of public member contains native type" in WinPRT

Tags: visual-c++, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, winprt

I'm trying to create a runtime component which supports windows phone 8. I had a c++ source, at present it won't support with the windows phone 8, so I'm converting them to windows phone runtime component to make it work with windows phone.

now the problem is I'd created them but shows error in the following,

```
    #pragma once
    #include "Encoder.h"

    namespace YakPRT
    {
     public ref class YakPRTComponent sealed
    {
      public:
        YakPRTComponent();
        void yakEncode(paTestData *yakData, uint8_t *rawData, int rawDataSize);
        void EncodeData(paTestData *yakData, uint8_t *rawData, int rawDataSize);
        void signalHandler( int signum );
                int yakRecordCallback( const void *inputBuffer, void *outputBuffer,
                           unsigned long framesPerBuffer,
                           const StreamCallbackTimeInfo* timeInfo,
                           StreamCallbackFlags statusFlags,
                           void *userData );
        PaError yakAudioStreamOpen(paTestData *yakData);
        PaError yakAudioStreamStart(paTestData *yakData);
        PaError isYakAudioStreamNotStopped(paTestData *yakData);
        PaError yakCloseAudioStream(paTestData *yakData);
    private:
        Encoder *_encoder;
      };
      }
```

the following errors coming from the above code,

error C3987: 'yakEncode': signature of public member contains native type 'paTestData *'

error C3992: 'getYakCodec': signature of public member contains invalid type

Note: paTestData is a structure,

```
    typedef struct
    {
         int          frameIndex;  /* Index into sample array. */
   FILE        *recFileStream; /* Record the stream into File */
   uint8_t     *encoderOutput;
   int         allocOutputSize; /* memory size allocated */
   int         encoderOutputSize;
   PaStream    *recordStream;   /* PaStream opened to record Audio callback. */
   AVContext *c;
    } paTestData;
```

I'm not good with c++, would somebody please say me what is this error, and how to rectify this. .